# How to create your own linux distro?

Tags: linux, resources, operating-system, kernel, distro

Is there any resource or book for creating own linux distro.Only good resource i found is [this](http://www.informationweek.com/news/software/showArticle.jhtml?articleID=205917063)

And also what specialities need to start project like this?

Comment: Not programming-related, pushing to superuser.

Comment: There is always Suse Studio, for the lazy among us :)

Comment: The biggest question **why**?

There are many ways, beginning from creation of simple LiveCD with specific tools up to creating totally new distribution like Mandriva, Debian or Suse...

So, what do you ask?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you should first look [linuxfromscratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/)

Answer (score 0):

From the deep end, [linuxfromscrach](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) is basically a manual to create a distribution.

On the shallow end, you can do a [fedora respin](http://fedoraunity.org/re-spins-info/faq/fedora-media-and-the-re-spins), or [SUSE Appliance](http://www.novell.com/partners/technology/isv/appliance/getting_started.html)